# Trying to make gnuplot use custom colors from the third column of a file

Tags: plot, gnuplot

```
John     10479 228c44
Tom      5780  4fffa7
Willia   5248  773095
Salem    4747  ea1c1s
john     4630  db2f0d
```

`plot "data.txt"  using 2:xtic(1):(1):3 with boxes lc rgb variable title "Messages sent"`

`**2:xtic(1):(1):3**`

- **2**       decides height
- **xtic(1)** put the names of the first column on the X tics
- **(1)**    *should* be the boxwidth
- **3**       *should* be the column gnuplot takes the rgb color from

instead, i get "skipping data file with no valid points" and nothing shows up

if i only use the first three `2:xtic(1):(1)`
for some reason, gnuplot uses the third part (`(1)` instead of `xtic(1)`) as the xtic names and ignore `xtic(1)`

i have no idea what causes that either

i just want to save column colors in hex rgb format in files instead of using linestyles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, column 3 should be integer numbers not strings. So, add `0x` in front of column 3 to make them hexadecimal values. Alternatively, you could write a function to convert them to hexadecimal values.

The sequence is essential. `xtic()` is always last. Variable color is second last. The plotting style `with boxes` can be used with either two or three columns (check `help boxes`). However, you can use is also with just one column, then gnuplot takes the pseudocolumn 0 as implicit x-values. Apparently, together with a column for variable color gnuplot gets confused.
So, you have to specify the x-column explicitly.
And you can specify the width of the box separately, e.g. `set boxwidth 0.8`.

So both will work:

```
plot $Data u 0:2:(0.8):3:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var
```

and

```
set boxwidth 0.8
plot $Data u 0:2:3:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var
```

**Script:**

```
### with boxes and variable color
reset session

$Data <<EOD
John     10479 0x228c44
Tom      5780  0x4fffa7
Willia   5248  0x773095
Salem    4747  0xea1c1s
john     4630  0xdb2f0d
EOD

# set boxwidth 0.8
set style fill solid 0.3

plot $Data u 0:2:3:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var ti "Messages sent"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: worked thanks! i have tried the 0x part before but didnt know xtic should always be at last so i still get errors and i assumed it wasnt the problem